# Waterline (Sails.js): AND conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm using mongodb with sails.js querying a model that contains the titles of torrent files. But I'm not able to perform a waterline query using the "AND" condition. I've already tried it in several ways but most of them return empty or simply, never return.

e.g. the database contains an entry with:
    `"title": "300 Rise Of An Empire 2014 720p BluRay x264-BLOW [Subs Spanish Latino] mkv"`

When adding each query parameter line by line:

```
var query = Hash.find();
query = query.where({ "title": { "contains": "spanish" } });
query = query.where({ "title": { "contains": "2014" } });
query = query.where({"or": [ { "title": { "contains": "720p" } }, { "title": { "contains": "1080p" } } ] });
```

It returns entries containing "2014" AND ("720p" OR "1080p"), some of them also contain "spanish" but I think it's just a coincidence.

How can I specify "spanish" AND "2014" AND ("720p" OR "1080p)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution but it's really a mongo one :

```
query = query.where({"$and": [ { "title": { "contains": "720p" } }, { "title": { "contains": "1080p" } } ] });
```

Notice the `$and` key?

From sails-mongo source :

```
/**
 * Parse Clause
 *
 * <clause> ::= { <clause-pair>, ... }
 *
 * <clause-pair> ::= <field> : <expression>
 *                 | or|$or: [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $or   : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $and  : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $nor  : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | like  : { <field>: <expression>, ... }
 *
 * @api private
 *
 * @param original
 * @returns {*}
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var query = {
  title: [
     { contains: "spanish"},
     {contains: "2014"}
  ],
  or: [
     {title: { contains: "720p" } },
     {title: { contains: "1080p" } },
  ]
};

Model.find(query).exec(function(err,items) {
  ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, returns an empty set.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't notice. You can see the results from db queries, using the method in my first post, [here](http://37.187.9.5:1337/hash/search?query=spanish). They are truncated. Just edit the "query" parameter in url to search for different terms. You can also use something like `2014 spanish 720p | 1080p` as argument, [link](http://37.187.9.5:1337/hash/search?query=1024%20spanish%20720p%20|%201080p), [sample output](http://pastebin.com/est2YbCN).

Comment: I ended up using a text index on title field so everything has changed now, thanks anyway.