# Waterline/Sails.js/Mongo How to use AND conditions in query for one filed?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

My question is same to [Waterline (Sails.js): AND conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461235/waterline-sails-js-and-conditions). There is a answer but it's not work for me (neither for the questioner).

As far as I know , waterline doesn't have keyword 'and' in its query language.
If I have multiple conditions to query, I can simply use:

```
MyModel.find({fieldA:valueA, filedB:valueB});
```

But my question is how to do:

```
MyModel.find({fieldA:{
   contains:keyword1, 
   contains:keyword2
}});
```

For I can't set two key with same name in Object/JSON, so I tried :

```
MyModel.find({fieldA:
  [
   {contains:keyword1}, 
   {contains:keyword2}
  ]
});
```

and

```
MyModel.find({fieldA:
  {contains:[keyword1,keyword2]}
});
```

and

```
MyModel.find()
.where({fieldA:{contains:keyword1})
.where({fieldA:{contains:keyword2}});
```

But none of them work as expected : 1st and 2nd one returns empty set and 3rd one only contains keyword2.
It appears that when you trying to add two 'contains' condition to a same filed(fieldA), with chained 'where' method, the second one will overwrite the first one.

I'm using the native  mongoDB's way to handle this as a workaround, Dose anyone know how to do this in waterline's way ? Or is this a issue should be reported on github.

PS:sorry for my poor English :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, multiple `contains` are not supported. Whether it's an omission or a feature request is debatable. At least for an SQL case, it's a stupid simple fix (though took me over an hour to find it) to be able to support something like:

```
orm.collections.user.find({
            and: [
                { name: { contains: 'neil' } },
                { name: { contains: 'armstrong' } }
            ]
        });
```

All it needs is a `case 'and':` in in the following file and it works:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-sequel/blob/master/sequel/lib/criteriaProcessor.js#L120

I suspect the Mongo case would be similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time !:) So I should report this as a bug(or send a feature request ) on github ?

Comment: Can make this work on mongo... wonder whether I'm doing something wrong or if waterline is really far behind

Comment: Well it does work! See my answer! Use $and instead of and for mongo

Comment: Did somebody raised an issue on github for this?

Answer (score 4):

Well I found the way it should be done for a mongo database.

You should be able to combine multiple criterias on the same field using the `$and` key :

```
orm.collections.user.find({
        $and: [
            { name: { contains: 'neil' } },
            { name: { contains: 'armstrong' } }
        ]
    });
```

Sails-mongo source code shows this :

```
/**
 * Parse Clause
 *
 * <clause> ::= { <clause-pair>, ... }
 *
 * <clause-pair> ::= <field> : <expression>
 *                 | or|$or: [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $or   : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $and  : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | $nor  : [<clause>, ...]
 *                 | like  : { <field>: <expression>, ... }
 *
 * @api private
 *
 * @param original
 * @returns {*}
 */
```