# Waterline: query array using AND for elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, waterline, sails-mongo

I have a model with `{ title: 'title', tags: ['foo', 'bar'] }`. How would I query all documents containing tags `foo` AND `bar` at same time without going native?

I tried

```
ContentEntry.find({tags: ['bar', 'foo'] })
```

but this returns documents having EITHER `foo` OR `bar` in `tags`, while I'm interested in having both tags.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact answer in similar SO topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/33145145/679052
This is rather a workaround only for sails-mongo adapter which allows you to use $and operator